# Can I generate a page after pressing a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know how apparent it is from the title so I will explain it a little bit more. I'm on a passion project that has the same idea of a game site like the old ones, Miniclip and Friv in mind.

What I am thinking of doing but don't know if is possible is this: When you want to play a game (let's say you want to play snake so you pressed on it), create a completely new HTML page using a template(a page that didn't exist till now) and have that game on the page.

What I'm curious about is if it's possible and how should I approach doing this.

Comment: You're basically looking for a [web framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework). You could just do this using plain javascript - but why reinvent the wheel when you can leverage existing work.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. But there's nothing more that can be answered here unless you share what you've tried

Comment: If you want to create a new page on the website then you need **server-side** code to do it. That could be written in JavaScript so long as your hosting supports some kind of server-side JS (typically this would use Node.js). You need to learn the fundamentals of web development. This is far too broad a topic for a SO question.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean by creating a page that didn't exist using a template. Is it just opening a new window that display the game?